# Labels with white (or other color) background

Tags: qgis, labeling, color

I tried to give my labels somekind of box and a backgroundcolor (or boxcolor) in QGIS, but i couldnt find the right option.
My labels are not readable because my layers are too dark.
I found offset but would prefere a small box in white.
Can u help me?

Comment: It's a feature planned for 2.0 release. see the discussion http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Road-shield-labels-td5005058.html and the ticket http://hub.qgis.org/issues/2180

Answer (score 5):

You can create **Halo Text** as as current workaround

[image]

This Guide runs through labeling in QGIS

http://mapeoamano.org/en/manuals/how-to-prepare-a-high-resolution-large-format-map-using-qgis

Comment: I'd recommend new labeling though. (In 1.8: The 'abc' button in labeling toolbar - NOT labeling in layer properties.)

Comment: Its useful to know that its not possible, yet.
So I can stop searching for it in the options.

Meanwhile i will go with halo-text, thx.